# Pyspark - DataFrame Merge Column data

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a DataFrame like this ;

```
+---+------+-----+-----+-------+
| id|status|Flag1|Flag2|   type|
+---+------+-----+-----+-------+
|123|   N/A| null|false|Prepaid|
|123|   N/A| true| null|Prepaid|
+---+------+-----+-----+-------+
```

i want to do like this ;

```
+---+------+-----+-----+-------+
| id|status|Flag1|Flag2|   type|
+---+------+-----+-----+-------+
|123|   N/A| true|false|Prepaid|
+---+------+-----+-----+-------+

 Flag1 -> Flag2 
 ---------------
 True -> False = True 
 True -> null = True 
 False -> null = False 
 True -> True = True
 False -> False = False
```

The reverse logic is the same.
Flag1 and Flag2 both cannot be empty

How can I do it with Pyspark?

Comment: is it just one id or there are multiple. Even if it is one, the outcome can vary. Please add more rows of data and also modify sample output

Comment: Please update your question and add details like what is the logic for merging records e.g if "Flag1" or "Flag2" has multiple non-null values which boolean operation to perform. Also which attributes to group by? "id", "type"?

Comment: @wwnde I'm filtering when entering at first, there can't be more than 2 data for the same id.

Comment: @Azhar Khan I updated the content